# Are there more 0s or 1s?

Tags: computer-science

It's kind of (really) stupid to ask and could not be more unprecise, but anyway, at worst this thread creates some additional 0s or 1s on stackoverflow's server.

**If all disks in the world where shredded into bits,** 
could you think of any argument reasoning for which staple would be taller: 0s or 1s?

Comment: Just a guess, but the staple of 0s would probably be taller, as unallocated disk space is typically 0'ed in many environments.

Comment: Or if SSD will be more popular (cheap) would be more 1's, cause new erased NAND memory cell is 0xFF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Benford's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law), which is also applicable to the digital number system, there will be more 0s.

Moreover, analogously to the arguments in Benford's law, one can argue that in integral numbers, which are in more than 99.9% fixed length, the more significant bits are usually mostly 0s. E.g. consider a 32 bit integral number, where the biggest possible value is about 4*10^9 (or 2*10^9, if the number is signed). Usually, not the full possible range is used, so for example numbers up to 1 million will always have 12 leading 0 bits, regardless of the other bits, which can be considered to be almost random for values up to 1 million for this example. You can use this chain of arguments for any other maximum bound within fixed length integral numbers.